# Can we represent partitions by mutually parallel lines in the plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-geometry, simplicial-complexes, matroid-theory, matching-theory

Lately I have become interested in the following idea:  Suppose $n$ is a positive integer and $[n]=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$.  Suppose we have 3 distinct partitions $b$, $g$, and $r$ of $[n]$.  Assume that the subsets in each partition are denoted $b_i$, $g_i$, and $r_i$.  The basic question is whether or not we can "draw" this triple in the following way:  I want the elements of each subset $b_i$ to lie on a line parallel to the $x$-axis, the elements of each subset $r_i$ to lie on a line parallel to the $y$-axis, and the elements of $g_i$ to lie on a line parallel to the diagonal line $y=x$.

Consider, for example, this drawing/sketch:
[image]
This represents the triple of partitions given by
$$b=|1,3,6,10|2,5|8,11|4,9,13|7,12|,$$
$$g=|1,2,13|3,4|5,6|7,8|9,10|11,12|,$$
$$r=|1,12|2,3|4,5|6,7,13|8,9|10,11|.$$

In the drawing, one can see what is meant by "representing the partitions with zones".  Each partition is represented by a family of mutually parallel lines (also known as a zone), either blue, red, or green, in the sense that the lines in the zone distinguish the points according to which subset they lie in.  I would like to know generally when a triple of partitions has a *faithful* representation in the sense that the lines are in bijective correspondence with the parts of the partitions.  For example, is there a characterization of faithfully-realizable triples of partitions based on forbidden minors (whatever that would mean for triples of partitions)?

One can think of several natural ways to generalize this.  For example, we may consider more than 3 partitions.  We might represent partitions using cosets of a vector subspace in a larger vector space than the plane.  We might use cosets in a ring or a module.

This idea of drawing partitions in this way seems natural to me, but I have not found anything about this after a cursory literature search.  (I don't know what better educated people would call these things.)  It looks like a topic in matroid theory or combinatorial geometry.  I included the tag simplicial-complexes because these partitions induce a "colored" simplicial complex on $[n]$.  This also reminds me of matching theory.

Comment: How would you draw the triple b=[123|456|789], r=[147|258|369], g=[159|267|348], i.e., horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines on a square? It seems to me that no matter in which order you take rows/columns you cannot get all the green lines to line up.

Comment: Federico:  This is certainly a "degenerate" triple.  Thus, if you write the linear equations that require this triple to be represented by parallel lines, then one will see that all the points must be represented by the same point.  Thus, this triple does not have a faithful representation by parallel lines.